# Loading a Rectangle upon mouse hover in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have an item that consists of an image:

```
Item {

    /* other stuff */

    Image {
            id: img
            anchors.fill: parent
    
            source: mySource
            asynchronous: true
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        }
}
```

I want to overlay a (transparent) rectangle of the same size on the image when one hovers over it, so that I can do stuff like provide captions for the image etc.

How would one go about doing this?

1. My first try below: (I used console statements to verify that hovering on an image itself works)

```
import QtQuick 2.6

Item {
    Image {
        id: img
        anchors.fill: parent

        source: mySource
        asynchronous: true
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

        MouseArea {
            enabled: img.status == Image.Ready
            anchors.fill: parent
            
            hoverEnabled: true
            onEntered: {
                console.log("Entering: ")
                overlay
            }
            onExited: {
                console.log("Exiting: ")
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id : overlay
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "transparent"

            Text {
                id: imgcaption
                text: "Caption"
                anchors.bottom: overlay.bottom; anchors.verticalCenter: overlay.verticalCenter
                font.pointSize : 14
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I do this I get something like this at all times, regardless of if I'm hovering over the image or not.
[image]

2. I also tried to put the Rectangle inside the `onEntered` handler itself, but when I do this the image doesn't display at all, and neither do the console statements so I'm not sure if this is valid QML.

It should be fairly obvious that I'm new to QML and don't really know what I'm doing, so I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try toggling the visibility based on the `containsMouse` property, like this:

```
Item {
    Image {
        id: img
        anchors.fill: parent

        source: mySource
        asynchronous: true
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea
            enabled: img.status == Image.Ready
            anchors.fill: parent
            
            hoverEnabled: true
        }

        Item {
            id : overlay
            anchors.fill: parent

            visible: mouseArea.containsMouse

            Text {
                id: imgcaption
                text: "Caption"
                anchors.bottom: overlay.bottom; anchors.verticalCenter: overlay.verticalCenter
                font.pointSize : 14
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[HoverHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-hoverhandler.html) might be better. It's born to deal with hover events so you don't have to set `hoverEnabled` or `anchors`.

More importantly, it's transparent for mouse movement. This would be useful in more tricky scenarios, such as dealing with hover events for an item that already contains interactive controls (Button, Flickable, MouseArea, etc).

If you still use MouseArea in such cases, it may interrupt how these controls deal with hover events while HoverHandler won't. (MouseArea has a `propagateComposedEvents` property, which only controls whether *clicked*, *doubleClicked*, and *pressAndHold* would be propagated or not.)